# How to compute a limit with exponential functions?

Tags: limits

So i have this double variable limit

$$\lim_{(x,y)→(0,0)} \frac{e^{x+y}}{e^x-1}$$

I am new studying limits and my first thought was to plug in the x and y values, however it would get me an undefined solution , or else 1/0

Can somebody please show me the steps in order to compute the limit of this equation ? Thanks!

Edit: for reference, the solution on the answer sheet is as follows, but it doesn't really make any sense to me

The numerator clearly tends to 1, being a continuous function. The denumerator depends only on x and
goes to 0± as x goes to 0 from the right or from the left, that is, as (x, y) goes to (0, 0) staying in the left
half-plane or in the right half-plane (the function is not defined on the y axis). Therefore the limit is +∞ if
(x, y) → 0 and x > 0 and it is −∞ if (x, y) → 0 with x < 0.

Comment: 1/0 is not really considered as undefined, rather it is worth $\pm \infty$ depending on wether $x$ is going to 0 from positive or negative values. Have you ever seen such limit ? What is your definition of limit by the way (rigorous with $\epsilon$ or just behavior that one could see on a graph) ?

Comment: I am not really sure. The question justs ask to compute the limit, with no further definitin

Comment: "... find the limit" does not make sense: the limit simply does not exist as you have observed. More or less the same as $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{e^x-1}$ does not exist.  What is your question?

Comment: Ok but you've never seen the definition of limit in some other context of your course ?

Comment: My question reguards also how the solution explains the problem , orelse : Therefore the limit is +∞ if (x, y) → 0 and x > 0 and it is −∞ if (x, y) → 0 with x < 0.

Comment: If "the limit" exists at all, it must be unique. As you have already observed, the fraction behaves differently for $x<0$ and $x>0$, so it does not exist. Same reasoning for $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$, which does not exist either.

Comment: I'm sorry for being this persistent but, how do i know that it behaves differently from x being smaller or greater than 0? I didn't write the solutions and its  my first time studying limits to any help on how to get this x smaller or x bigger than 0 would be great

Comment: What books/notes are you using? I think there is no point in considering this problem if one does not understand why $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$ does not exist: $\lim_{x\to0-}\frac{1}{x}=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty$.

Comment: The 1/x is due to the fact that we are only taking into consideration the x on the denominator and the numberator 1 is because the limit of the numerator is just one ? correct? excuse my languag